# Guarantee that Dispose is called "when the process is ending"

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dispose, shutdown

There is a possibly-shared resource, X *associated with foreground threads*, that is used by two instances (Y, Z) and supplied as a dependency. Because X may be shared it cannot be Disposed of by either usage site (Y or Z).

The obvious solution would be to ensure that X is *manually* Disposed 'at some appropriate time' after it is no longer used: in this case it can be assumed this implies that X is no longer strongly-reachable. However, in this case there is a [buggy] client that does not do so.

Since X has an associated foreground thread this can keep the process from terminating (completely?).

Is there a way that X - without external dependencies, or even knowing if such is in an 'executable' or 'Windows Service' - ensure that a call to Dispose occurs before/as the process is terminating?

Is there a more intelligent way to handle such an (untracked) shared resource which may have one or more consumer(s)?

Currently this is relying on the finalizer but, as advertised, such is .. non-reliable.

Comment: What signifies "the process is ending" to you? The termination of all forground threads except the one X is running on? or do you have a more definite signal like a event that is raised or a flag that is set to `false` which breaks a `while` loop out?

Comment: Can you get process instance? and hook up to Process Exited event?

Comment: @Viru The event wont fire because the thread from `X` is keeping the process alive.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I suppose 'all other foreground threads'. However this is probably a miscalculation on my part; and I'm not even the immediate owner of such threads. The threads are created/owned by the RabbitMQ client - and the RabbitMQ message board rightly [explains why foreground threads are appropriate](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2010-January/005796.html).

Comment: Another option goes something like 'make every Y/Z dispose X, unless instructed not to do so' .. or at least that pushes the error elsewhere, which is better (in this case) than having a process that doesn't reliably terminate.

Comment: I think I may have a hacky solution that could do it, it is basicly your finalizer solution but instead of the finalizer use a timer checking a list of WeakRefrences. I don't have the time right now but I will write up a formal answer tomorrow morning with code examples. EDIT: of course the best solution is "Fix the buggy client and stop trying to do work arounds", but this is the real world.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm definitely willing to entertains options. I thought WeakReferences were (directly) tied to the GC .. and if so, would this be in the same boat as the finalizer?

Comment: You can do a `GC.Collect()` inside the timer before you enumerate the list to see if any references are still alive. I would make the timer slow, maybe only once every minute or more, there is a performance penalty to calling `GC.Collect()`. Like I said, this solution is a hack and I would not make it your first choice solution.

Comment: Can you adapt the processes that use X? In that case a simple form of reference counting would be the standard solution.

Comment: As I wrote up a solution I realized some problems with my plan. this may take longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not call dispose on X but it will tell you when all X have been collected by the GC (And forces a GC every 5 minutes)

```
public sealed class CollectionWatcher<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T> _objectFactory;
    private readonly List<WeakReference> _references;
    private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    private readonly Object _lockObject = new Object();

    public CollectionWatcher(Func<T> objectFactory, double minutesBetweenChecks = 5)
    {
        _objectFactory = objectFactory;
        _references = new List<WeakReference>();
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutesBetweenChecks).TotalMilliseconds;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;
    }

    public T GetObjectBecauseICantBeTrustedToDisposeCorrectly()
    {
        var result = _objectFactory();
        var wr = new WeakReference(result);
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            _references.Add(wr);
            _timer.Start();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public event EventHandler AllItemsCollected;

    private void OnAllItemsCollected()
    {
        AllItemsCollected?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }


    private void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool allItemCollected = false;

        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced, false);
        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            foreach (var reference in _references.Where(x => !x.IsAlive).ToList())
            {
                _references.Remove(reference);
            }

            if (_references.Count == 0)
            {
                _timer.Stop();
                allItemCollected = true;
            }
        }

        if (allItemCollected)
        {
            OnAllItemsCollected();
        }
    }
}
```

You can't just call `Dispose()` on `T` because by the time `.IsAlive` is false the finalizer has already been called on `T`.

I am going to keep thinking on this, maybe there could be other solutions.

Comment: This answers the question, although I've not tried it practice ~ we decided on just sucking up problem with the code designed elsewhere and changing the contracts such that it is *invalid* to dispose the shared resource from inside any of the container and it's *invalid* for the process to end without manually disposing the (now always external) resources. An annoying mess to cleanup, but now it's done :}